# Using EV to Schedule Event for Later

Tags: perl, events, event-handling

I'm using EV to periodically (every 5 minutes) query my "event queue" table, and fire off any events that are past their "trigger" time.  This works great.

But often, the trigger time will be days or weeks in the future.  Because I know the trigger time so far in advance, I should be able to reduce the frequency of my EV loop but still fire off the event at the exact time requested, rather than having to wait until the next iteration of my loop.

Is there a way to do this in EV?  I suppose creating a watcher on the fly would be the solution?  How is this done?

Comment: Please add some pseudocode or a concrete example of what you want to achieve. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
use constant DB_CHECK_PERIOD => 5*60;

sub handle_db_events {
   my ($w) = @_;

   while (1) {
      my $secs = ...get seconds to earliest unprocessed event from the db...;

      $secs //= DB_CHECK_PERIOD;
      if ($secs > 0) {
         $w->set($secs > DB_CHECK_PERIOD ? DB_CHECK_PERIOD : $secs, 0);
         return;
      }

      ... process events that have expired and delete them from the db ...;
   }
}

my $w = EV::timer(DB_CHECK_PERIOD, 0, \&handle_db_events);
handle_db_events($w);
```

If you can't delete the records from the DB, you can set a flag in the record saying it's been processed or you can use a hash indexed by record id.

I'm assuming `$w` is passed to the callback as the first argument. Adjust if not.

Comment: I think this is what I want to do, but can't see how in EV's documentation.  The question is how do I create a timer event from within the periodic event, where the timer event lives on its own? Or am I over-complicating?